# How to query with a where clause in mysql json table

Tags: mysql, json

I am using mysql 5.7.x

I can create a mysql json table

```
 CREATE TABLE t1 (jdoc JSON);
```

I can insert rows.

```
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES('{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}');
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES('{"key1": "value11", "key2": "value22"}');
```

I can also get all rows:

```
SELECT * from t1;
```

How do I use a where clause?

```
select * from t1 where "key1" = "value1"
```

Comment: How am I supposed to search for `value1` over multiple keys `(key1, key2, etc...)` in an `OR` condition?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can try:

```
SELECT *
FROM t1
WHERE json_extract(jdoc, '$.key1')='value1'
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE json_extract(jdoc, "key1") = "value1";
ERROR 3143 (42000): Invalid JSON path expression. The error is around character position 1 in 'key1'.

Comment: if I use json_extract(JSON, "key1") I get this error: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'JSON' in 'where clause'

Comment: Oh sorry for my mistake. Thanks for the correction @Tampa.

Comment: @Tampa it should be `$.key1` and not simply `key1` as the 2nd argument for the JSON_EXTRACT() function.

Comment: How am I supposed to search for `value1` over multiple keys `(key1, key2, etc...)` in an `OR` condition? @Sterls