# Group and count from condition in array mysql

Tags: mysql, group-by, count

i have table groupLocal:

| id | nameGroup | group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | group A | [1,2] |
| 2 | group B | [2,3] |

and table customer:

| id | nameCustomer | local |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jerry | 1 |
| 2 | Tom | 2 |
| 3 | Nan | 2 |
| 4 | Bie | 3 |

i want result count customer.local with condition customer.local in groupLocal.group

| id | nameGroup | count(customer.local) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | group A | 3 |
| 2 | group B | 3 |

Thank U

Comment: is that `group` column a `varchar` or `json` column? if its a `json` column, [its been answered before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38432862/mysql-where-in-from-json-array)

Comment: It's generally better to normalize your design instead of putting a list in a column. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Comment: what is in groupLocal.group?  are those customer.local values?  can you explain what you are counting?  how is the count for group B 2?

Comment: @BagusTesa it is json

Comment: @ysth yes, it's 3, I updated it again.

Comment: @Barmar Thank so much, I have been receptive...

Comment: what does `select version();` show?