# How to perform a search query from data in json format Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel

I have a table called listings with a column named variants which saves data in json format like so.

```
"[{\"bed\":\"2\",\"size\":\"2564\",\"price\":\"12999999\",\"ppsft\":\"5,070.20\"},{\"bed\":\"3\",\"size\":\"3426\",\"price\":\"3999999\",\"ppsft\":\"1,167.54\"},{\"bed\":\"4\",\"size\":\"4123\",\"price\":\"4999999\",\"ppsft\":\"1,212.71\"}]"
```

I want to perform a search query but I want to consider the "bed" value only while searching. There are multiple filters like location, type category e.t.c. saved as strings, so how do I extract this("bed") and perform a search query? here is an example of one of the filters

```
<?php

namespace App\ListingSearch\Filters;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

class TypeId implements Filter
{
    public static function apply($builder, $value)
    {
        return $builder->where('type_id', $value);
    }
}
```

Comment: is that actually a JSON type field?

Comment: @AndrewAngute have you checked this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32188341/how-to-query-with-a-where-clause-in-mysql-json-table/32188481

Comment: @lagbox  $table->json('variants'); this is how am saving to the database

Comment: @MihailMinkov I checked it out, still not able to extract and search

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to perform search query on json based comlumn with laravel eloquent:

For exact match of search query, we can use `whereJsonContains`

```
product::whereJsonContains('variants->color', $color)->get()
```

For partial match of search query match, we can use `whereRaw`

```
product::whereRaw("JSON_EXTRACT(variants,'$.color') Like ?", ["%$color%"])->get()
```